# Flutter SQFlite: Having trouble with updating the listview with database contents

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, local-storage, sqflite

I did somehow managed to get the database contents to show via listview. However, its not doing it properly. As soon as i run the emulator the contents stored in the database should appear, but they don't. It also shows that the database is empty even though it clearly isn't. But once i add a new item to the database and click save, everything shows up (except the one i last added and it shows up on the next update). I have no clue how to fix this, i tried placing _listTodos() everywhere to see if it executes before the widgets but there wasn't any improvement. **The issue is in the ListDisplay class** I think, so you can just skip over the rest, I just have the entire code for convenience.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'model/todo_model.dart';
import 'model/todo.dart';

class ListGradesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  ListGradesPage({this.title, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _ListGradesPageState createState() => _ListGradesPageState();
}

var _todoItem;
var _lastInsertedId = 0;
final _model = TodoModel();

Future<void> _deleteTodo() async {
  _model.deleteAllTodo();
}

class _ListGradesPageState extends State<ListGradesPage> {
  //final _model = TodoModel();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: () {
                print('editing...');
                //_listTodos();
              }),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () {
                print('deleting all...');
                setState(() {
                  _deleteTodo();
                });
              }),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListDisplayPage(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddGrade()),
          );
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListDisplayPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ListDisplay createState() => ListDisplay();
}

class ListDisplay extends State<ListDisplayPage> {
  int _selectedIndex;

  List<Todo> todos = new List<Todo>();

  Future<void> _listTodos() async {
    todos = await _model.getAllTodos();

    if (todos.isEmpty) {
      print('it is empty-2.');
    } else {
      print("not empty-2");
    }

    print('To Dos:');
    for (Todo todo in todos) {
      print(todo);
    }
  }

  _onSelected(int index) {
    _selectedIndex = index;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


    _listTodos();

    // _listTodos() is not calling the function above for some reason, but executes everything below it
    // In the database there are items stored however it says the databse is empty...
    // until i add a new item and everything shows up except the item i recently added


    if (todos.isEmpty) {

      print('To Dos:');
      for (Todo todo in todos) {
        print(todo);
      }

      print('it is empty.');
    } else {
      print("not empty");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Color clr = Colors.transparent;

    return todos.isEmpty
        ? Center(
            child: Text(
                'Nothing to show! Is it empty? ' + (todos.isEmpty).toString()))
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: todos.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                //                           <-- Card widget
                child: Container(
                  color: _selectedIndex != null && _selectedIndex == index
                      ? Colors.lightBlueAccent
                      : Colors.transparent,
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _onSelected(index);
                          print(index);
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(

                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                        child:
                            Text(todos[index].sid + '\n' + todos[index].grade),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
  }
}

class AddGrade extends StatelessWidget {
  String _sid, _grade;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add Grade"),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Student ID',
                  labelText: 'SID',
                ),
                onSaved: (String value) {
                  print('Saving SID $value');
                  _sid = value.toString();
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Student Grade',
                  labelText: 'Grade',
                ),
                onSaved: (String value) {
                  print('Saving Grade $value');
                  _grade = value.toString();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _formKey.currentState.save();
          _addTodo();
          //_listTodos();
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.save),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _addTodo() async {
    Todo newTodo = Todo(sid: _sid, grade: _grade);
    _lastInsertedId = await _model.insertTodo(newTodo);
  }
}
```

Console Output (on execution):

```
Restarted application in 1,607ms.
I/flutter (14196): To Dos:
I/flutter (14196): it is empty.
I/flutter (14196): not empty-2
I/flutter (14196): To Dos:
I/flutter (14196): Todo{id: 1, sid: q, grade: qq}
I/flutter (14196): Todo{id: 2, sid: w, grade: ww}
I/flutter (14196): Todo{id: 3, sid: e, grade: ee}
I/flutter (14196): Todo{id: 4, sid: r, grade: }
I/flutter (14196): Todo{id: 5, sid: hh, grade: kk}
```

Screenshots of emulator, before adding new student, and after adding new student (the recent one doesn't show up either until I add another student again),

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp8cH.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJI1y.png)

I apologize if i didn't follow the guidelines, never really posted questions on here before.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)? I would suggest wrapping your `ListView.builder` in a future builder and passing in the `_loadTodos` function as the future. Then you can remove all of the initState code that initializes the todos.

Generally, I find that doing async work in `initState` doesn't always work. The UI has already built, and doesn't know to rebuild when the async work is complete. Another option might just be to call `setState` once the async function completes with the todos. I would think that the FutureBuilder is the better way to do it though.

If you need some additional help, let me know. I could probably write some of it out for you.